# Tensorflow models error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, chatbot

I am testing some chatbots from Github, I seem to get the following error whenever I try running chatbots using tensorflow.

after typing `python train.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tf_seq2seq_chatbot.lib.train import train
  File "C:\Users\S\Downloads\ChatBot-master\ChatBot-master\tf_seq2seq_chatbot\lib\train.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tf_seq2seq_chatbot.lib.seq2seq_model_utils import create_model
  File "C:\Users\S\Downloads\ChatBot-master\ChatBot-master\tf_seq2seq_chatbot\lib\seq2seq_model_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from tf_seq2seq_chatbot.lib import seq2seq_model
  File "C:\Users\S\Downloads\ChatBot-master\ChatBot-master\tf_seq2seq_chatbot\lib\seq2seq_model.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.models.rnn.translate import data_utils
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.models'
```

Source https://github.com/AhmedAbdalazeem/ChatBot

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [tensorflow.models repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models).